# Uninitialized constant Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a web service to access my database via mysql, but I keep getting this error : NameError - uninitialized constant Mysql

When I created the Database, i did not add a password to it. I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio.
To test the web service i am using Advanced REST client.

This is my code

```
get '/all_users/' do
conn=Mysql.new('localhost','My-PC\Nikki','', 'My-PC\Project')
recordsArray = "{\"clientList\":["
clientArray = Array.new
sql = 'select * from ServerUsers'
records = conn.do(sql) do |record|
    client = AndroidtableClientsSearch.new(record[0],record[1],record[2],record[3], record[4])
    clientArray<<client.to_s
end
conn.logoff
recordsArray<<clientArray.join(',')
recordsArray<<"]}"
recordsArray
end
```

Comment: You can use Microsoft SQL Management with mySQL ?

Comment: I am new to this, I don't know. If there is a different, correct way, please recommend. I am open to any ideas.

Comment: try follow this [**tutorial**](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/) but i think the sintaxys is wrong... should be something like `con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'user12', '34klq*'`

Comment: if you're using Rails why not use Active Record ?

Comment: By the way there are different products which give SQL database, Microsoft SQL managament is for Microsoft SQL Server, mysql has mysql workbench and phpmyadmin.
others are sqlite , postgresql , oracle sql , etc, there are also NoSql databases :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza apparently some old abandoned stuff, not sure http://superuser.com/questions/163610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error. You also need to install the mysql gem. Running 'gem install mysql' fixed this for me.